# Android double back click for returning to previous activity

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, back-button

I have encountered an issue with android stack exchange client. Here are my steps:

1. Open digest email in gmail client
2. Click on a question
3. Stack exchange client with selected question opens
4. Click back button
5. Feed activity is displayed
6. Click back button again
7. *The same question is displayed again*
8. *Click back button again*
9. *Feed activity is displayed again*
10. *Click back button again*
11. Gmail client activity with digest is displayed

I suppose 7-10 items shouldn't be there. I use the latest stack exchange client and nexus 9 with the latest android 5.0.1. It's constantly reproduces for me for 1-2 months and just on Nexus 9.

It also reproduces for me on Nexus 4. Android version 5.0.1. App version in both cases  - 1.0.51

**UPDATE**

Tried again on 1.0.56 and it still reproduces for me. I've recorded screencast with the issue by SDK screenrecord tool. Here is youtube link with it - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zf04LJ9IORA&feature=youtu.be

If you need i can get adb logs\other data if it helps.

Just tested it on Nexus 4 and 56 and it works fine, but somehow it doesn't work on nexus 9

Comment: Reproduced on Nexus 4, Lollipop 5.0.1, app version 1.0.52. I hope you can add more info about your app version and Nexus 4's Android version to cross-check, since I'm now guessing it's Lollipop-only issue.

Comment: You are right, it also reproduces on nexus 4 and i updated question. I remembered that it works fine on nexus 4.... May it was working on 5.0.0 version

Comment: Whoa this is crazy, repro'd on my end, digging deeper.

Comment: Yep, only happens on 5.0, on 4.4.2 hitting back instantly takes you back to Gmail. Down the rabbit hole we go!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was fun. We had an issue where we were calling `finish()` to, well, finish the activity when you were hitting "Back" and we knew it was the last page visible in the app (so hitting back from the Feed in a normal case or hitting back from a deep link page like in your example) but since `finish()` doesn't immediately kill the activity, the rest of the logic below that code was still getting triggered, which included something along the lines of "if the current page isn't the feed and we are out of pages to show, show the feed when the user hits back" so the second the deep link page got removed the feed showed up too.

This caused it to go into a loop, as you saw, because we were creating pages to display while also removing some and the logic is a mess. That looping issue is fixed.

On top of that, the user flow here didn't make much sense to begin with. If you come in from a link in another application and hit back *you should go back to that application, not the feed* and starting with version 1.0.53 (hitting beta later today) that's exactly what we'll do.

Comment: Whoa, that was fast. Thanks for the fix and detail explanation!

Comment: Hi @Kasra, looks like the issue is still occurs for me :( I have installed 1.0.54 on Nexus 9 (5.0.1) and it still reproduces for me with the same steps. Once or twice it worked fine for me, but then it started again. I've tried to Force Close app, but issue still appears.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov Looking into it, I'm planning on releasing 1.0.55 tomorrow so hopefully I can figure out what's going on before then.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov I'm not able to reproduce this again, it might be due to other changes I've made for 1.0.55 though. I'm pushing 1.0.55 right now, let me know if you see it happen on that version?

Comment: Ok, thanks. i also will try to clear user data and try to reproduce it again in 1.0.55

Comment: Tried again on 56 and it still reproduces for me :( I've recorded screencast with my steps and added them to my question as UPDATE.